# Performance tuning on ORDER BY statement with filter for one result

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql

I have the following simple query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 message 
FROM Log l 
WHERE l.id_fk = '##Guid##'
AND l.id_category IN ('Category 1', 'Category 2') 
ORDER BY l.timestamp DESC
```

The execution time on large Log tables without an nonclustered descending index on `timestamp` is very long because the complete list has to be ordered first to get the top 1 entry.

Is it possible to get rid of the order by statement or is creating the index completely the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think the fastest approach is this more complex query:

```
SELECT TOP (1) message
FROM ((SELECT TOP 1 l.message, l.timestamp
       FROM Log l 
       WHERE l.id_fk = '##Guid##' AND
             l.id_category = 'Category 1'
       ORDER BY l.timestamp DESC
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT TOP 1 l.message, l.timestamp
       FROM Log l 
       WHERE l.id_fk = '##Guid##' AND
             l.id_category = 'Category 2'
       ORDER BY l.timestamp DESC
      ) 
     ) l
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

This can take advantage of an index on `log(id_fk, id_category, l.timestamp)`.  Unfortunately, SQL cannot use the index on `timestamp` with `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 message 
FROM (select l.timestamp,l.message
        FROM Log l 
        WHERE l.id_fk = '##Guid##'
        AND l.id_category IN ('Category 1', 'Category 2') 
        ) x
ORDER BY x.timestamp DESC
```

Just written off top of head, basically the inner query filters your data conditions to a smaller set, then orders to get the top 1

Answer (score 0):

The query is fine. You want this index:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx ON log (id_fk, id_category, timestamp DESC);
```

Or even this:

```
 CREATE INDEX idx ON log (id_fk, id_category, timestamp DESC, message);
```

Thus the greatest timestamp for the two categories can be quickly looked up. With the latter index it is not even necessary to read the table.

Comment: @Christopher Aside: The _term of art_ for the second suggestion is a [_covering index_](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/).